# The relationship xx was not loaded because the type xx is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

when i try to create migration for my code first context i get this error:

Errors: The relationship 'Exiled_Trader.Models.TradeContexts.Item_AdditionalProperties' was not loaded because the type 'Exiled_Trader.Models.TradeContexts.Property' is not available.

my Item Model has more than one many to many relationships to Property table which are used in few different properties. here how it looks like:

```
 public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            AdditionalProperties = new List<Property>();
            NextLevelRequirements = new List<Property>();
            Properties = new List<Property>();
            Requirements = new List<Property>();

        }

            public int ItemId { get; set; }
            public List<Property> AdditionalProperties { get; set; } 
            public List<Property> NextLevelRequirements { get; set; }
            public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
            public List<Property> Requirements { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the property model:

```
public class Property
{
public Property()
        {
            Values = new List<PropertyValue>();
        }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyValue> Values { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayMode { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? Progress { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the Item fluent api configuration:

```
 HasKey(i => i.ItemId);

            HasMany(i => i.AdditionalProperties)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Item)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ItemId);

            HasMany(i => i.Properties)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Item)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ItemId);

            HasMany(i => i.NextLevelRequirements)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Item)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ItemId);

            HasMany(i => i.Requirements)
                .WithRequired(p => p.Item)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ItemId);
```

Could anyone tell me what am i missing and why im getting this error?
Additional Properties, Properties, NextLevelRequirements and Requirements all use the same model class, is this the problem and should i make a different model class for each of those properties even if they are the same? Should i use composite keys instead maybe?

Comment: Why do you have 4 lists of `Property` in your item class? How  do you think that would be reflected in a DB schema. Additionally - why are you instantiating your lists in the constructor? EF will do all that work to create navigation properties for you. All in all, your schema is greatly flawed at this point. Try and articulate what you are trying to achieve with your schema.

Comment: In database i want to have 1 Property table.

I want my Item model in ef to reference this table in 4 different properties that would all be stored in Property table. I also want those 4 different properties in Item to reference different instances (not the same instances) of Property objects.

Also i instantiating my lists in constructor becasue thats what a guy in my tutorial said i should do, i guess it isint needed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and remove the constructors as well as the multiple navigation properties of the same type in your `Item` class. The EF will do all the hard work in terms of creating instances for your navigation properties so you don't need to do that. Likewise, your fluent api configuration will need to loose the extra definitions for 1:M relationships with the `Property`.

```
    public class Item
    {

        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    }

    public class Property
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? DisplayMode { get; set; }
        public int? Type { get; set; }
        public int? Progress { get; set; }

        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PropertyValue> Values { get; set; }
    }
```

This will create you the two tables - one for `Item` and one for `Property` with the 1:M relationship.

Comment: That would probably work but i wish i could have 4 different one to many properties that all are linked to Property table. How could i distinguish which type of Property i want to access, without defining a "propertyType" column in Property model?

Comment: Well, you can't, but even your initial approach would have never worked because all those 4 lists would contain the same elements as there is no additional criteria to separate them by. If you want this custom separation into 4 different lists, then you would be looking at creating another model class and mapping manually or using something like `Automapper` to create 4 different lists out of the 1 list the EF would return for you. I assume your `Type` property in the `Property` class is the additional criteria you are looking to separate these lists by.

Comment: Its not even possible with composite keys?

Comment: Not from a database point of view because you would define the composite key in `Property` class but that still links to a single `Item` using ItemId. Are you trying to do this because you see a lot of use cases in your codebase where you would need to filter the main list by property type to get one of the 4 lists you tried to create here?

Comment: I thought it would be handy to have it set up like this becuase all of those properties would have exactly the same declaration and i didint wanted to duplicate code, it seems i just lacked imagination out of lack of experience. Thank you for your help.